# Issue reading Text files with html tags and convert them into htmldoc VBA

Tags: html, vba, text

I have already downloaded the webpage as html and stored in local folder. Now, I want to read the same html file using excel VBA macro and parse for particular tag. The issue is : the html tag attributes are getting changed when i try to read from the local html file and assign the entire file data as html.

I was not able to get the correct html attributes, hence i was not able to parse it. when i try to read the html, then assign to a html object and write back the data into a file, i see the below results. Thats the reason i was not able to parse correctly for td.classname = "detb".

for ex: 
part of the original tag as in the local html file

```
<tbody>
<tr height=""22"">
<td width=""40%"" class=""detb"" colspan=""1""></td>

<td align=""right"" class=""detb"">Mar 13</td>
<td align=""right"" class=""detb"">Mar 12</td>
<td align=""right"" class=""detb"">Mar 11</td>
<td align=""right"" class=""detb"">Mar 10</td>
<td align=""right"" class=""detb"">Mar 09</td>
</tr>
```

Below is the kind of data when i read the file and assign to a html object and display/ write back to a file:

```
<tbody><tr height="""" 22""""="""">
<td width="""" colspan=""1"" 1""""="""" 40%""""="""" detb""""=""""></td>

<td align="""" right""""="""" detb""""="""">Mar 13</td>
<td align="""" right""""="""" detb""""="""">Mar 12</td>
<td align="""" right""""="""" detb""""="""">Mar 11</td>
<td align="""" right""""="""" detb""""="""">Mar 10</td>
<td align="""" right""""="""" detb""""="""">Mar 09</td>
</tr>
```

Code :

```
Set MyBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With MyBrowser
    .navigate << html file path >> 
    .Visible = True

    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document


    Open myFilePrev2 For Output As #1 
    Write #1, HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML
    Close #1

    .Quit
End With
```

Can you please help me.

Cheers,
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

```
Write #1, HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML
```

should be

```
Print #1, HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264524(v=office.14).aspx

> Unlike the Print # statement, the Write # statement inserts commas
>   between items and quotation marks around strings as they are written
>   to the file. You don't have to put explicit delimiters in the list.
>   Write # inserts a newline character, that is, a carriage
>   return–linefeed (Chr(13) + Chr(10)), after it has written the final
>   character in outputlist to the file.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your suggestion. i will try that. More than writing the content to a file, my issue is primarily reading the text file with html tags and assign the entire file to a htmldoc. I attempted this write back strategy just to check how local text file (with html tags) has been read, as it was not providing all the attributes as it was in the original html file.  To be clear, issue is post opening the html file in internet exp & saving sourcecode to "HTMLDoc", i am not able to get the tag condition  "td.classname = "detb" which is exists in the input html...